# Wait until specific elements loaded

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website and there are many elements I am dealing with. I need to wait for elements to be loaded.

This is my try till now but I am waiting a long time and sometimes I get errors.

```
.FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1").Click
.Wait 2000
GoBack1:
Set elePrint = .FindElementById("IconImg_CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_print", timeout:=20000, Raise:=False)
If elePrint Is Nothing Then
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"): GoTo GoBack1
Else
    elePrint.Click
End If
GoBack2:
Set eleExport = .FindElementById("theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn", timeout:=20000, Raise:=False)
If eleExport Is Nothing Then
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"): GoTo GoBack2
Else
    eleExport.Click
End If
```

Is there a better way for doing this?

This is the html part

```html
<tbody><tr valign="middle"><td height="21" width="5" style="background-image:url('aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/../dhtmllib/images/skin_standard/button.gif');background-position:0px 0px;"></td><td id="theBttnCenterImgbobjid_1545656314367_dialog_submitBtn" align="center" class="wizbutton" style="padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;background-image:url('aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/../dhtmllib/images/skin_standard/button.gif');background-position:0px -42px;"><nobr><a id="theBttnbobjid_1545656314367_dialog_submitBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="wizbutton" role="button">Export</a></nobr></td><td height="21" width="5" style="background-image:url('aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/../dhtmllib/images/skin_standard/button.gif');background-position:0px -21px;"></td></tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten this to

```
Do 
Loop While .FindElementsByCss("#theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn").Count = 0
```

Though you should set a timeout

```
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
Dim t 
t = Timer
Do 
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While .FindElementsByCss("#theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn").Count = 0
```

There won't be an error and there is no need to yield control. If the item is not found the `.Count` will be zero.

If the id is dynamic and you have a constant substring (which only occurs for one id attribute on the page (to be safe - may not be essential) you can use ^, *, $ operators in css). For example, if the start string is constant across pages change the css selector to

```
[id^='theBttnbobjid']
```

If occurs more than once, and the index is constant across pages then use the index to interact later e.g.

```
.FindElementsByCss("[id^='theBttnbobjid']")(2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I have noticed that this `#theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn` is changeable. How can I deal with it in this case ..? I am dealing with many pages and each time has different selector !! that's too weird

Comment: Yes that is true ..I have inspected another page and this was the result `theBttnbobjid_1545656314367_dialog_submitBtn`

Comment: I think so.. can it be implemented by partial text? But when searching for `dialog_submitBtn` I found three instances but the beginning is different in the three so can we rely on the start part too `theBttnbobjid`?

Comment: I tried such a selector `theBttnbobjid_*_dialog_submitBtn` but doesn't select anything.. I see your edit but how to include the start part too?

Comment: Ok It is there but this is for start only

Comment: I am sorry. I thought I have posted the html part but it seems I have posted in in another thread at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911876/download-file-to-specific-directory-using-selenium-excel-vba?noredirect=1#comment94669621_53911876) ... I have included the html part too here

Comment: I found two instances with that beginning .. so if possible I need a solution for start and end parts together ..so as to get just one instance

Comment: The second one .. is the target

Comment: Is it always the second one? If so you can use the method above but when you come to interact with the target use index .FindElementsByCss("[id^='theBttnbobjid']")(2) . I  think indices are 1 based in selenium otherwise use 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for awesome help. You are a legend

Answer (score 4):

You can try looping your elements until they become available.

```
On Error Resume Next
Do While .FindElementById("theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn") Is Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop
On Error Goto 0
```

I would also consider adding a timer to your loop if for some reason the the webpage hangs - which if this is the case you could reload the webpage or perform some other error handling operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. That worked better than mine

Comment: why hello there! +

Answer (score 1):

Shorter alternative:

```
Do While Not .FindElementById("theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn").IsDisplayed 
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in my codes:

.FindElementById("theBttnbobjid_1545642213647_dialog_submitBtn").WaitDisplayed