# VBA Selenium download PDF without dialog

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to open Chrome with some options

```
Set driver = New ChromeDriver
driver.AddArgument "--kiosk-printing"
driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
```

Kiosk-printig works fine, but when I try to save/download the PDF opened in Chrome, the file save dialog still opens.
What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
Public Sub browser_open()

Set driver = New ChromeDriver

driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "C:\PDF_folder\"
driver.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
driver.AddArgument "--kiosk-printing"
driver.Start "chrome"
driver.get "https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf/7/642/64176-haier/wm6002a.pdf?80517c2674ab60981d9ebd32535ca98d"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have had mixed luck with that but try this which just includes an extra line about setting a default directory https://stackoverflow.com/a/53912638/6241235

Comment: @QHarr , thanks for your reply. I did as you said, but when you try to download, a save window still appears, but printing without confirmation at the same time works. I added my code to the main post. Maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere?